# Is this true? $\forall x, y \in\mathbb{Q}: (\sin(x)=\sin(y))\Rightarrow (x=y)$

Tags: trigonometry

I just thought about the following expression:

$\forall x, y \in\mathbb{Q}: (\sin(x)=\sin(y))\Rightarrow (x=y)$

I think it is true because values of $\sin(x)$ only repeat every $\pi\times n$th time, which is never reached by any rational number.

Is this true? Or am i wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Your argument would apply equally to $\cos(x)$, but your conclusion would be false (because $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$, and if $x$ is rational, then so is $-x$). So you have to be a bit more careful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that

$$\sin x - \sin y = 2 \sin \tfrac{x-y}{2}\cos \tfrac{x+y}{2}.$$

A product is $0$ if and only if at least one factor is $0$. What are the zeros of $\sin$ and $\cos$? Which are rational?

Comment: Thanks, this formula helped me:) The only rational root of $sin(x)$ is $0$ and $cos(x)$ has none, so the expression is only zero if $x=y$.